# Obtaining MD5 hash value from online image / movie using Python

Tags: python, html, web, http-headers, md5

I'm currently looking to put together a quick script using Python 2.x to try and obtain the MD5 hash value of a number of images and movies on specific websites. I have noted on the w3.org website that the HTTP/1.1 protocol does offer an option within the content field to access the MD5 value but I'm wondering if this has to be set by the website admin? My script is as below:-

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.samplesite.com")
c.request("HEAD", "/sampleimage.jpg")
r = c.getresponse()
res = r.getheaders()
print res
```

I have a feeling I need to edit 'HEAD' or possibly r.getheaders but I'm just not sure what to replace them with.

Any suggestions? As said, I'm just looking to point at an image and to then capture the MD5 hash value of the said image / movie. Ideally I don't want to have to download the image / movie to save bandwidth hence why I'm trying to do it this way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's rare that servers will actually respond to requests with an MD5 header. You *can* check for that, but in most cases, you'll actually need to download the video or image, unfortunately.

(At least [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) is simple!)